# Retrieving and printing a value from an Access database

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, ms-access, pypyodbc

I'm trying to retrieve and print a row from an Access database. I want the user to input an ID and a field then a value to be printed.

This is my code so far...

```
import pypyodbc
import pandas

conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Operator\Documents\T31_DB.accdb;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM [TABLE_SIGNAL_ID]')

data = cursor.fetchall()
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
dfi = df.set_index([0], drop=False)
ID = raw_input("enter signal ID:")
ID = int()

res = dfi.iloc[[ID]]

print res
```

Is there a way I can keep the headings from Access so I can pull specific items from the row? don't want to rename the columns by hand because there are too many.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Is there a way I can keep the headings from Access" - Use pandas' `read_sql_query()` to populate the DataFrame. That will create the corresponding column names for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it but using SQL!

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
import sqlalchemy

conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Operator\Documents\T31_DB.accdb;')

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [TABLE_SIGNAL_ID]', conn)
dfi = df.set_index("signal_id", drop=False)

ID = raw_input("enter signal ID:")

res = dfi.loc[ID, ["signal_id", "abname", "system_id"]]

print res
```